# scaling diagrams in a table

Tags: tables, tkz-euclide, scale

Can anybody help me scale the elements in my table? It does render but it gives me error messages which go away if I just keep pressing enter, any help with the code so it just runs?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

%Diagram enviroment    
\newenvironment{diagram}
{\begin{center}\vspace*{10pt}\begin{tikzpicture}}
    {\end{tikzpicture}\vspace*{-5pt}\end{center}}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{diagram}[scale=0.5]
      \tkzDefPoints{-2/0/A,2/0/B,0/3/C}
    
            \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](C,A)\tkzGetPoint{E}
            \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](C,B)\tkzGetPoint{D}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=1.5](C,A)\tkzGetPoint{F}
            \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=1.5](C,B)\tkzGetPoint{G}
    
                
            \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
                %\tkzDrawPolygon(D,E,C)
                    
            \tkzDrawSegment(A,E)
                    \tkzDrawSegment(B,D)
    
                     \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
                         \tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
                         \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
                     \tkzLabelPoints[left](E)
                         \tkzLabelPoints[right](D)
                  \tkzLabelPoints[left](F)
                         \tkzLabelPoints[right](G)
    
                            \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,C)
                            \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](B,C)
    
                            \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](B,A,C)
                            \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](C,B,A)
    %\tkzDrawSegment(B,F)
    %\tkzDrawSegment(A,G)
    \end{diagram}
    &
    \begin{diagram}[scale=0.5]
      \tkzDefPoints{-2/0/A,2/0/B,0/3/C}
    
            \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](C,A)\tkzGetPoint{E}
            \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](C,B)\tkzGetPoint{D}
                
        \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
                %\tkzDrawPolygon(D,E,C)
                    
            \tkzDrawSegment(A,E)
                    \tkzDrawSegment(B,D)
    
                     \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
                         \tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
                         \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
                     \tkzLabelPoints[left](E)
                         \tkzLabelPoints[right](D)
                   \tkzLabelPoints[left](F)
                         \tkzLabelPoints[right](G)
    
    
                            \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,C)
                            \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](B,C)
    
                            \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](B,A,C)
                            \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](C,B,A)
     \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](B,F)
    %\tkzDrawSegment(A,G)
    \end{diagram}
    &
    \begin{diagram}[scale=0.5]
      \tkzDefPoints{-2/0/A,2/0/B,0/3/C}
    
            \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](C,A)\tkzGetPoint{E}
            \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](C,B)\tkzGetPoint{D}
                
        \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
                %\tkzDrawPolygon(D,E,C)
                    
            \tkzDrawSegment(A,E)
                    \tkzDrawSegment(B,D)
    
                      \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
                          \tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
                          \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
                      \tkzLabelPoints[left](E)
                          \tkzLabelPoints[right](D)
                          \tkzLabelPoints[left](F)
                          \tkzLabelPoints[right](G)
    
                            \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,C)
                            \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](B,C)
    
                            \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](B,A,C)
                            \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](C,B,A)
     \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](B,F)
    \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](A,G)
     \end{diagram}
     \end{tabular}


     \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) It is better not to use `scale`. As the author points out

> I recently discovered a problem when using the ”scale” option.
>
> ....
>
> There is still a foolproof method which consists in avoiding the use
> of scale = .... It’s quite easy if, like me, you only work with fixed
> points fixed at the beginning of your code. The size of your figure
> depends only on these fixed points so you just have to adapt the
> coordinates of these.

(1b, update) `scale` is triggering the issue but it not the cause. See the last note added.

(2) You can insert a `tikz` figure into a tabular but not the environment `diagram`, suitable for use with text.

Since all diagrams are similar, three commands have been added to change the coordinates in  block.

[image: A]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

%\usepackage{showframe}

%Diagram enviroment    
\newenvironment{diagram}
{\begin{center}\vspace*{10pt}\begin{tikzpicture} }
        {\end{tikzpicture}\vspace*{-5pt}\end{center}}
    
\newcommand{\AB}{0.7}   % A  and B added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\C}{1.0}    % C added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\Asize}{0.25}   % Angle added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=0.5]
        \tkzDefPoints{-\AB/0/A,\AB/0/B,0/\C/C}
        
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](C,A)\tkzGetPoint{E}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](C,B)\tkzGetPoint{D}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=1.5](C,A)\tkzGetPoint{F}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=1.5](C,B)\tkzGetPoint{G} 
        
        \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
%%      %\tkzDrawPolygon(D,E,C)
        
        \tkzDrawSegment(A,E)
        \tkzDrawSegment(B,D)
        
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
        \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](E)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](D)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](F)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](G)
        
        \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,C)
        \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](B,C)
        
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=\Asize](B,A,C)
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=\Asize](C,B,A)
%%      %\tkzDrawSegment(B,F)
%%      %\tkzDrawSegment(A,G)
    \end{tikzpicture}
    &
    \begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=0.5]
        \tkzDefPoints{-\AB/0/A,\AB/0/B,0/\C/C}
        
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](C,A)\tkzGetPoint{E}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](C,B)\tkzGetPoint{D}
        
        \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
        %\tkzDrawPolygon(D,E,C)
                
        \tkzDrawSegment(A,E)
        \tkzDrawSegment(B,D)
        
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
        \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](E)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](D)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](F)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](G)       
        
        \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,C)
        \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](B,C)
        
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=\Asize](B,A,C)
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=\Asize](C,B,A)
        \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](B,F)
        %\tkzDrawSegment(A,G)
    \end{tikzpicture}
    &
    \begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=0.5]
        \tkzDefPoints{-\AB/0/A,\AB/0/B,0/\C/C}
        
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](C,A)\tkzGetPoint{E}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=2](C,B)\tkzGetPoint{D}
        
        \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
        %\tkzDrawPolygon(D,E,C)
        
        \tkzDrawSegment(A,E)
        \tkzDrawSegment(B,D)
        
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
        \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](E)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](D)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](F)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](G)
        
        \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,C)
        \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](B,C)
        
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=\Asize](B,A,C)
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=\Asize](C,B,A)
        \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](B,F)
        \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](A,G)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Fixing the issue**

At least in this case, the problem seems to be localized with the `\tkzMarkAngle` command failing when the `size` value is small (around 0.2, after scaling).

It can be fixed  using a new definition with just a simple option to `\tkzMarkAngle` (it will work with any value of `size`, even 0):

```
\makeatletter
    \def\tkz@MarkAngle[#1](#2,#3,#4){%
        \begingroup
        \pgfqkeys{/tkzmkangle}{#1}
        \tkzFindSlopeAngle(#3,#2)\tkzGetAngle{tkz@dirOne}
        \tkzFindSlopeAngle(#3,#4)\tkzGetAngle{tkz@dirTwo}
        \tkzNormalizeAngle(\tkz@dirOne,\tkz@dirTwo)
        
        \def\tkz@mymark{\pgfsetplotmarksize{\tkz@mksize}\pgfuseplotmark{\tkz@markang}}
        % draw the arcs
        \begin{scope}[decoration= {markings, mark=at position \tkz@mkpos with {\tkz@mymark}}]
            \tkzDrawArcRAN[#1,fill=none]%
            (#3,\tkz@size)(\tkz@FirstAngle,\tkz@SecondAngle)%
        \end{scope}
        \endgroup
    }
\makeatother
```